# Resize Windows partition without affecting Ubuntu in dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed both Windows and Ubuntu on a single hard-drive. The Windows OS is split into 2 partitions, C and D and I want to enlarge the C partition by taking 3GB from the D partition. Can I do this using the Disk Management from Windows and without affecting the Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you will not be changing any partition labels or disk identifier strings and such, there should not be any problems. But first be sure to **MAKE A BACKUP**. Then first shrink partition. And after that enlarge partition.

Comment: Thank you. I will make a backup before trying to resize the partition